# Starfield SSL not trusted by iOS 14.6

Tags: ios, ssl

We're using the Starfield Root Certificate Authority - G2 SSL certificate and it appears not to be trusted since iOS 14.6 - neither in the app (API calls get rejected) nor in Safari. Does anyone know what happened? I can see this root certificate is still on the list of trusted certificates by Apple and it works on earlier iOS versions.

Comment: Check the used certificate. Apple has introduced restrictions regarding the maximum validity period of a certificate (max 1 year). If the validity period is too large Apple considers the certificate as invalid.